# How do I get PMD reports & the details therein without using I/O?

Tags: java, pmd

I am trying to generate a PMD report by using a custom ruleset. The input is a bunch of Apex classes in String format. Without outputting to a file, I'd like to then parse the report contents directly (XML format) to create a summary of violations, begin/end lines, priority, the rule name, and the message attached. This is to be done on multiple bodies of Apex code, adding to a report bean every time there is a violation.

I was trying to do this with SourceCodeProcessor, but couldn't figure out what some of the required objects/arguments looked like, nor how they were built. I still don't know how to make a RuleContext object property.

Any help is massively appreciated.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you are trying to achieve. Why are you coding directly on top of PMD instead of using the PMD tool (Ant or CLI should work for Apex projects)... Maybe some extra context would help here.

Comment: Trying to package a custom ruleset and PMD as part of a code analysis tool. We get code classes from a database and run them through a gauntlet of analyses, including code cleanup. Would like to avoid having to create temporary directories and files of the classes and reports to process them, hence looking at SourceCodeProcessor, etc. We want to have a summary of all violations from the PMD reports at the end of our program's run.

Comment: Also, @Johnco, do you think the Ant task would work for this? Running thru CLI isn't an option since we want to ship this, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you intend to do, I'd take a slightly different approach (I'm a PMD maintainer).

`SourceCodeProcessor` is very low-level. It's the actual place where the whole analysis process is orchestrated, but misses most of the interesting setup to get there.

Also of note, `SourceCodeProcessor` deals with **a single file**. For Apex this may currently not make a difference, but PMD is increasingly moving towards crossing info between analysis (ie: we have plans to extend the current Data Flow Analysis / Control Flow Graph code to inter-process calls), so being able to let PMD control the complete project analysis on a single run would be best.

Therefore, I'd take a look at [`PMD.doPmd`](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-core/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/PMD.java#L247). You should probably write your own version of such method, but cover most of the basics:

1. create a `PMDConfiguration` object with your setup (threads, rulesets to be used, etc.)
2. have the `RuleSetFacory` create a ruleset based on your configuration
3. obtain a `List<DataSource>` with the sources to analyze
4. create a `RuleContext`
5. setup [a listener for the report](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-core/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/PMD.java#L271-L280). This would allow you to obtain violations directly as POJOs (you can avoid actually generating a report file and parsing it)
6. call [`PMD.processFiles`](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-core/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/PMD.java#L392) to actually do the analysis.

The one point where you should diverge from what PMD currently does is step 3. Instead of pointing to files (`FileDataSource`), you should create a list of [`ReaderDataSource`](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-core/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/util/datasource/ReaderDataSource.java), using a [`StringReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) around the source code string you retrieved from the db.

It's very little code on your end, just wiring up differently pieces already in PMD.

P.S. One extra advantage of this approach, is that being `PMD` a very high level class of PMD, it´s among the least likely to undergo an API change in future releases. PMD has recently adopted semantic versioning, and the upcoming release (6.0.0) will introduce several API changes / remove deprecated methods and classes.

P.S. 2: this is probably not the best place to ask for this... it's mostly by chance I came across this, and I don't think anyone not familiar with PMD internals would be able to help. You may want to reach out to the PMD development team more directly (development mailing list, Github, so on).

Comment: Thanks very much. I am a little lost as to why I need threads specified in the PMDConfiguration object, and am not sure what to do with RuleContext as the documentation is rather minimal. Would you be willing to elaborate? Also, I did talk to adangel, and he said that GitHub was also a good idea. However, should I just add issues on GitHub? When I was about to do that, the site suggested using StackOverflow instead.

Comment: I cannot run PMD.processFiles() on a list of ReaderDataSource. What's the workaround there? Write a custom processFiles() method?